# Circle and a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, circles

Q: The polygon circumscribes the circle. Find the perimeter.

[image: http://imgur.com/ENFz3]

Comment: What do you know about 2 tangents to a circle intersecting at a point?

Comment: What are the measurements of exactly. What do you want the perimeter of?

Comment: I'm looking for the perimeter of the square, and I don't ever remember seeing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is a fact that any two intersecting tangents are equal in length.

Thus, the perimeter is $2(9+7+5+8)=58$

Answer (score 0):

It's a basic theorem in euclidean geometry: a quadrilateral circumscribes a circle iff the sum of the lengths of both pairs of opposite sides is the same. This follows at once from the fact that Amr reminds in his answers: both tangents to a circle from an exterior point to the circle have the same length.

From this the perimeter of your quadrilateral is 58.